# Issue with stored procedure: "Too many arguments"

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

This seems to be a fairly common issue and I'm scratching my head as to why it's happening. I'm working with a software application where I don't have access to the source code directly (I can view some with .NET Reflector only).

The stored procedure goes like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CS_GetMessages] (
    @CustomerID C_ID, @Level C_Integer, @UsersTimeZoneOffset C_Integer
    )
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    DECLARE @Date Datetime
    SELECT @Date = CONVERT(nvarchar(10), getutcdate(), 101)

    SELECT
        [MessageID]

    FROM
        [dbo].[Messages]
    WHERE
        ([CustomerID] = @CustomerID OR [CustomerID] IS NULL) 
        AND Enabled = 1
        AND Deleted = 0
        AND (EffectiveDate IS NULL OR @Date >= CONVERT(nvarchar(10), DATEADD(minute, @UsersTimeZoneOffset, EffectiveDate), 101))
        AND (ExpiryDate IS NULL OR @Date < CONVERT(nvarchar(10),  DATEADD(minute, @UsersTimeZoneOffset, ExpiryDate), 101))
        AND Publish = 1
        AND Level = ISNULL(@Level, Level)
    ORDER BY MaintenanceDate DESC

END
```

Now, according to the source code (unfortunately because of licensing I can't paste it), it sends the appropriate amount of parameters. SQL Profiler shows this properly too:

```
exec CS_GetMessages @CustomerID=N'CT000001',@Level=NULL,@UsersTimezoneOffset=0
```

However, it tosses an error:

```
Error: 8144, Severity: 16, State: 2 Procedure or function CS_GetMessages has too many arguments specified.
```

But, if I run the procedure manually, it returns a value correctly. I used the following test code:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CS_GetMessages]
        @CustomerID = 'CT000001',
        @Level = NULL,
        @UsersTimeZoneOffset = 0

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Note that there is no data since the database is blank (empty table), so it appropriately returns 0. Any ideas of what could be happening?

UPDATE: Source code that does the database call:

```
 private SystemMessageManager LoadSystemMessages()
        {
            int paramValue = Conversions.ToInteger(Utility.DataFromSession("UsersTimezoneOffset", string.Empty));
            SystemMessageManager messageManager = new SystemMessageManager();
            CriteriaCollection loadCriteria = new CriteriaCollection();
            CriteriaCollection criterias2 = loadCriteria;
            criterias2.Add("CustomerID", DbType.String, Utility.GetCurrentCustomer().CustomerID, ParameterDirection.Input, "");
            criterias2.Add("Level", DbType.Int32, null, ParameterDirection.Input, "");
            criterias2.Add("UsersTimezoneOffset", DbType.Int32, paramValue, ParameterDirection.Input, "");
            criterias2 = null;
            messageManager.Load(loadCriteria);
            this.CheckForDeactivation(messageManager);
            return messageManager;
        }
```

Comment: Do you specify more parameters in the code?

Comment: @Szymon No, the code shows the appropriate number of arguments (3).

Comment: Is it possible you have two objects with same name and different owners? Because in your working example you have `[dbo].[CS_GetMessages]` and on your code that you are getting the error you have just `CS_GetMessages` so, what if you specify the owner?

Comment: Also, extending @JorgeCampos comment, check your profiler traces and make sure that it is actually in the correct database when it executes.

Comment: @JorgeCampos It's the correct database. The strange part is, I have another install of this same application and it works perfectly fine. Same code and everything.

Comment: @NathanC Not only the database, the schema of the object. Could you try `exec dbo.CS_GetMessages @CustomerID=N'CT000001',@Level=NULL,@UsersTimezoneOffset=0` and see what happens? Here in my factory it is common mistake from the developers we have a schema for the objects and they have their users so, if they create an object without the schema name the application wont work because this object would be for the user of the developer.

Comment: In your stored proc, your parameter @CustomerID is defined as type "C_ID".  Could you please confirm that this is a NVarChar or VarChar.  In your examples, the one that fails is using a NVarChar and the one that works is using a VarChar (not always compatible).  If type "C_ID" is a compound or extended type (or class, etc), then that might be the source of your error.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Query executes successfully.

Comment: @tgolisch According to the code, it's using `DbType.String` as its type (it's a C# app).

Comment: @NathaC So then you have two objects with different owners therefore different signatures. Can I post as answer ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos How would this make a difference though? It works fine on the other application with the same user.

Comment: @JorgeCampos The query you gave executes with or without `dbo.` in the query. I copied/pasted the query from Profiler and it executes. It's only failing when in the application.

Comment: @NathanC So the application is using a connection user that has the same object with different signature. Can you see which user is the application using and if this user have the same grants as the user you are using in the Profiler?

Comment: @JorgeCampos In both cases, the user is an administrative user. I'm logged in as the application user in SSMS and it executes fine there, just not in the application (using the same user).

Comment: Then the only option I can think of is that is something wrong with the code, as you cannot post it it would be difficult to help. Can you post at least the procedure call part of the code?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Updated. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why do you have this line `criterias2 = null;` It seems not passing parameters at all

Comment: @JorgeCampos I don't know...I didn't code the application. It however seems to work since the "working" application has that exact same code. It's a headscratcher...

Comment: Well it is a headscratcher. Can you see the systems objects of the database that the application is connecting? Try to search all objects with the CS_GetMessages name

Comment: I'm thinking this is related to some sort of application/database mismatch on my end.

Comment: @NathanC, I suspect your Stored Proc instead of the C# code.  That is why I asked about the type "C_ID" in your stored proc (SQL server layer).  The definition of your stored proc shows that the first parameters is @ CustomerID with a type of "C_ID" (not VarChar or NVarChar).  Since "C_ID" is not a normal type in TSQL, I'm wondering what type "C_ID" is defined within your SQL server.  Whenever you use an extended type like that, there is always the chance of something special going along with it.

Comment: @tgolisch It's listed as `nvarchar(30)` as a user-defined type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CS_GetMessages] (
    @CustomerID C_ID, @Level C_Integer, @UsersTimeZoneOffset C_Integer
    )

Change your code to

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CS_GetMessages] (
    @CustomerID BigInt, @Level Integer=NULL, @UsersTimeZoneOffset Integer
    )
```

By default integer is 0 not null. So you need to specifically make it as null.

```
exec CS_GetMessages @CustomerID=1,@Level=NULL,@UsersTimezoneOffset=0
```